# Need to configure main thread execution time

Tags: java, multithreading, program-entry-point

I have a multithreaded application which takes around 1 hour to complete fully. I want to configure something so that after an Hour if the whole execution is not completed (i.e main is not completed) I need to have an alert in logs. In what way it can be configured.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

Keep track of the total number of threads you create and initialize the number of slots in the latch to that number. Pass a reference to the latch to each thread. In a finally block, at the end of the sub-threads's code, you should invoke `countdown()` right before the thread terminates.

In your main thread, after launching all the threads, you invoke the `await()` method. Optionally you can pass a timeout at which point you could force terminate your sub-threads, or call system.exit or something.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to schedule a command to run after a given period of time.  You can then write a method to log a message and hook it up to the `ScheduledExecutorService`.